# Node.js - How to send sessionID to GET method in Express via request package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, express-session, node-request

I'm trying to login to my Node.js (Express) app with another Node.js created script to try create a virtual bot on my app.

First, i sent a POST via "request" package to my /api/user/login and then i tried to get data from /api/user/session where i must be logged.

Request script:

```
request.post({
  url: "http://localhost:1717/api/user/login",
  form: {
    email: "xxx@xxx",
    password: "xxx"
  }
}, (err1, res1, body1) => {
  console.log(res1.statusCode); // console returned 200 cause login was successfull

  request.get({
    url: "http://localhost:1717/api/user/session",
  }, (err2, res2, body2) => {
    console.log(res2.statusCode); // console returned 401 cause im not logged
  });

});
```

Express script:

```
app.post("/api/user/login", (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = sha256(req.body.password);

  if(isValid(email) && isValid(password)) // for example
    req.session.userID = 1; // for example

    res.sendStatus(200);
  }

  else{
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }

});

app.get("/api/user/session", (req, res) => {
  const userID = req.session.userID;

  if(userID){
    res.status(200).send(req.session.id);
  }

  else{
    res.sendStatus(401) // Unauthorized
  }

});
```

Probably i need to send a valid cookie to GET method on Express. Please let me know how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: You need to enable a cookie jar, see 3rd example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#examples